# Does the multi curl takes multi time?

Tags: php

**Hello Everyone**

I want send and receive more than 50 api requests at the same time using cURL.
Becase each one request takes 5 second and If I use the sync type It will takes 250s.
So I try to get all request in 5~10s but not working correctly.

**Is it possible to receive all request one time?**

Thanks.

```
public function multiCurl()
    {
        // create both cURL resources
        $ch1 = curl_init();
        $ch2 = curl_init();
        
        $pageNum = 1;
        $date = Carbon::now();
        $date->toDateString();
        $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
        $prev6Months = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date." -6 months"));
        $apikey = "123123123123123";
        $productNum = 0;

        $outputType = "page=" . $pageNum . "/json/&filters=dataEmissao[" . $prev6Months . " TO " . $newDate . "]";
        $url = 'https://-------'. $outputType;

        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url. '&apikey='. $apikey);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        $pageNum += 1;
        $outputType1 = "page=" . $pageNum . "/json/&filters=dataEmissao[" . $prev6Months . " TO " . $newDate . "]";
        $url1 = 'https://--------'. $outputType1;

        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url1. '&apikey='. $apikey);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        //create the multiple cURL handle
        $mh = curl_multi_init();

        //add the two handles
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

        //execute the multi handle
        do {
            $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            if ($active) {
                curl_multi_select($mh);
            }
        } while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);

        //close the handles
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
        curl_multi_close($mh);
        $response_1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch1);
        $response_2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch2);

        var_dump("-------11111---------------->" . $response_1);
        var_dump("-------22222---------------->" . $response_1);
        die();
    }
```

Comment: First I want to possibility.

Comment: You must clear the problem! Is there any order between requests? or does any request depend to any other?

Comment: no.ch1 and ch2 is same api request to a server but the result are different via $pageNum. 
I combined it wit curl_multi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Multi-threading (Threadpool) to do that or use The `curl_multi_*` series of functions to make concurrent access possible.
However you used multi function but maybe in a wrong way. Read the following article and see different examples to run concurrent access.

[Using curl multi-threading to simulate the concurrency of the detailed](https://www.programmersought.com/article/78591475487/)